# How to give an variable inside pmax() in R

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose if I have a data iris and I want to apply pmax() to a list of dynamic columns.

```
Ex:
DT <- as.data.table(iris) 

example_column <- c("Petal.Width")

DT[, test_flag :=
     ifelse(pmax(substitute(example_column), Petal.Length) > 0, "Exclude", "Consider")]
```

But I am not able to pass example_column as an dynamic argument to pmax().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `do.call` with `.SDcols` if you have more than 1 column in `example_column`.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(iris) 
example_column <- c("Petal.Width")

DT[, test_flag := ifelse(do.call(pmax, .SD) > 0, "Exclude", "Consider"), 
                  .SDcols = c(example_column, 'Petal.Length')]
```

For single column using `get` is enough.

```
DT[, test_flag :=
     ifelse(pmax(get(example_column), Petal.Length) > 0, "Exclude", "Consider")]
```

Comment: neat, you can also do it with `mget` and drop `.SD/.SDcols`